# Google Cloud Messaging for Android with Quickblox

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, quickblox

I'm trying to build a mobile chat application using quickblox sdk. Everything is working fine only for the push message. I want a scenerio where users offline can read messages sent to them when they come online, so i stumbled on quickblox push message which uses Google Cloud Messaging. I have done the registration on Google APIs Console. If i send an offline message I can see it on my quickblox account but the notification doesn't show on my mobile device.

When I was doing the Google Cloud Messaging I noticed I was asked for IP address in which I submited the IP of my server. I thinking this is the cause of not seeing the notification on my device. Please I like to know if I am to submit my server IP or quickblox IP. Thanks

Comment: If you leave the list of accepted IP addresses in the API console blank, any IP is accepted. I don't see how you could have a problem with that.

Comment: Thanks #shyam out of curiosity made me make that statement, because everything seems to work fine only for the PUSH Message

Comment: It probably has got something to do with how you implemented the BroadcastReceiver in your android code which receives the push notification.

Comment: So, your issue is that you don't receive Android pushes on your device?

Comment: @user3655892 so which is the best GCM or Quickblox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution to the problem what I did was to check if user was online if yes use the standard sendMessage method else use quickblox push. That solved it. Bellow is the code used

```
@Override
public void sendMessage(String message) throws XMPPException {
    //Check if user is online or offline
    if (isOnline()) {
        chat.sendMessage(companionId, message);
    }else {
        StringifyArrayList<Integer> userId = new StringifyArrayList<>();
        userId.add(companionId);

        //Using PUSH notification
        QBEvent event = new QBEvent();
        event.setUserIds(userId);
        event.setEnvironment(QBEnvironment.PRODUCTION);
        event.setNotificationType(QBNotificationType.PUSH);
        event.setMessage(message);

        QBMessages.createEvent(event, new QBCallbackImpl() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Result result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onComplete(result);
                if(result.isSuccess()) {
                    //Message sent
                }
            }
        });
}
    }
```

Comment: what is the defination of isOnline?